# Devexpress wpf wrong exporting to Xls

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress Wpf GridControl v2011.2.

I try to export data to excel via standard devexpress' mtethods:

```
 XlsExportOptions options = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsExportOptions()
            {
                TextExportMode = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportMode.Text,
                ExportMode = XlsExportMode.SingleFile,               
                Suppress65536RowsWarning=true,
                ShowGridLines=true,
                SheetName=header

            };
 ((TableView)GridControlForExporting.View).ExportToXls(filename, options);
```

The end-user has Windows XP and Office 2007. this combination has problems. After exporting the data over 750 rows, the file has 750,751,752 merged rows (A750 merged with A751,A752; B750 with B751,B752 and so on). On windows 7 and office 2010 there is no such problems.

What can cause it?

**Solved**

The issue was solved with installing 2011.2.10 binaries.
There were some moments:

- enviroment was  as virtual machines
- devexpress components were trial

Comment: Please, [report this issue directly at DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=bugreport).

Comment: Good. I'll also track this ticket [B222029](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=B222029).

Comment: @DmitryG your link is broken, change please ".dev" to ".com"

Comment: Ups... corrected now. Thanks, Yuriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging, at least of columns is behavior by design because Devexpress is trying to export in a WYSIWYG manner to excel.

See [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q207570.aspx) for more

If it works on another machine, it could be because they layout of the grid is different there.

Comment: it does not work on windows XP machines. MS Office does not matter as I found out

Comment: No, it's combining columns if data or headers exceed whatever size i think. Try setting ShowColumnHeaders and ShowDataHeaders to false and see if the problem persists.

Comment: perhaps, then it must depends on screen resolution or dpi or something similar, doesn't it? I'll try these moments

Comment: Could be, i didnt really figure it out. We are exporting raw data as csv now which works fine.

Comment: I'll try to set ShowColumnHeaders or ShowDataHeaders to different values, thanks